# Custom headers in WordPress, are there also custom footers?

Tags: headers, footer, custom-header

I’m new to WordPress. I saw a custom header file in the `inc` folder of Twenty Twelve theme. I understand that we can use this custom header in any custom page template instead of header.

I have a doubt now, is there any custom footer that also can be used? Why this custom files should be stored in `inc` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [Custom Headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) documentation for information about it.

There is no "custom footer" feature, well because WP only has "custom header" [theme feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features) and it isn't named/scoped to handle arbitrary custom-something.

> why this custom files should store in "inc" folder?

This is just an implementation detail of specific theme, it's not required or standardized in WordPress. `inc` is short for `includes` and is typical name for folder containing PHP files (other common folder names being `php` and `src`).